# When do we specify restrictions in rational expressions or equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the following equation $x \neq 0$ apply's according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E3%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%2F%282x%29) (expanded form).

$$\frac{x^3 + x^2}{2x} = \frac{x^2 + x}{2}$$

Yet in the following [equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ab%5E2%2Fb%20%3D%205) it does not...

$$\frac{ab^2}{b} = 5 \iff ab = 5$$

Why don't we specify the restriction $b \neq 0$ here? And when do we specify restrictions in general?

Comment: I think this is an artifact of Wolfram Alpha's programming, not something required by mathematics.  Generally speaking, if there is a "removable" discontinuity (I.e. a hole), we don't give the notice $ x\neq a $. But, if the discontinuity isn't removable, we do denote the values for which the function is not defined.

Comment: $$\frac{ab^2}{b} = 5 \iff ab = 5$$ $$\text{iff}$$ $$b\neq 0$$

Comment: @Anorton how do I know if my equation has removable discontinuity or not? I'd have to draw it to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it must be implicitly understood that $b\ne0$ since $ab=5$ has no solutions when $b=0$.  Consider instead the equation $\frac{ab}b=5$.  In this case, the solution is indeed $a=5,b\ne0$.

Comment: So when $b \neq 0$ can be implied it shouldn't be mentioned? Otherwise it should be?

Comment: @user1534664 If $b$ can't be $0$ anyway, specifying $b\ne0$ would be redundant.  However, $(a,b)=(5,0)$ is clearly not a solution of $\frac{ab}b=5$ since $\frac{5(0)}0$ does not exist, hence $b\ne0$ should probably stated.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether my method is correct: So whenever I see a fraction in an expression or equation, I would have to take note that the denominator $\neq 0$. Then when the equation/expression is simplified I check if that condition (denominator $\neq 0$) is already implied within the simplified version. If yes then I omit the restriction, otherwise I explicitly define it.

Comment: @user1534664 I would probably say "state" rather than "define", but yes, I think that would work.  The solutions need to make sense in the original equation.  And they don't make sense if part of the equation does not exist.

Comment: I think I understand. So if I have 

$$\frac{(a + b)(a + b)}{(a + b)(a - b)} = \frac{a + b}{a - b}$$ 

Then I would have to say $a + b \neq 0$ right?

Comment: Hi can you please still say if my prev comment is correct?

Comment: @user1534664 You would probably want to state that, yes.  And if you had that fraction equal to $1$, you'd want to write the solution as $b=0,a\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

or $\frac{ab^2}{b}-5b=0$ is equivalent to $b(ab-5)=0$ the solution $b=0$ is senceless and we obtain $ab=5$.
And $\frac{x^3+x^2}{2x}-\frac{x^2+x}{2}=0$ if $x\ne 0$ sometimes a CAS ignore this case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the expression $e(x)=\frac {x^2}x$ is strictly undefined for $x=0$. But defining $e(0)=0$ we recover $e(x)=x$ for all $x$ rather than just for $x\neq 0$ and this value is required to maintain continuity.

In the second case, you could say that $b\neq 0$ is implicit in the equation, because $ab=5$ implies $b\neq 0$.

The first case is an identity except when $x=0$, so this needs to be stated, even though the gap can be repaired.

Comment: Is this a good thumb rule: if the end result of an equation implies a restriction we don't state it and otherwise we do?

Comment: How does one repair a gap?

Comment: @user1534664 The rule of thumb is "always be alert to a possible division by zero.

Comment: @user1534664 To "repair a gap" is my informal way of saying that the function $\frac {x^2}x$ has a removable singularity at $x=0$, which looks like a gap in the definition of the function, and this is removed (repaired) by setting the value to $0$ when $x=0$.

Comment: I don't understand when I should state a restriction. I try to be alert of division by 0, but sometimes it seems mathematicians dont always state it (like in my second example).

Comment: So how would you say in "math language" that $x = 0$ when using a particular function?

Comment: @user1534664 The first expression is written as an identity - it applies for a range of values of $x$ - but (without further definition) it does not apply when $x=0$. The second is an equation, and the value of $b$ can be determined.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb. I understand what you're saying, but I don't understand why you're saying it. Do you mean that if the value of a variable can be determined you don't have to specify a restriction?

Comment: @user1534664 In solving the second question, I would cancel $b$ and see what happened. I would note that this meant $b\neq 0$ and check at the end to see that this was a valid assumption. If the equation were $ab^2=5b$ I would proceed $b=0$ or $ab =5$.

Comment: "In solving the second question, I would cancel b and see what happened. I would note that this meant b≠0 and check at the end to see that this was a valid assumption." This is what I do too, and the step where I'm stuck at is: how do I know whether $b \neq 0$ is a valid assumption? I'm very grateful for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that
$$\dfrac{x^3 + x^2}{2x} = \dfrac{x^2 + x}{2} \Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
2x\cdot \dfrac{x^3 + x^2}{2x}=2x\cdot \dfrac{x^2 + x}{2}\\
2x\neq 0
\end{cases}$$
Also $$\dfrac{ab^2}{b} = 5 \iff 
\begin{cases}
b\cdot\dfrac{ab^2}{b}=b\cdot 5\\
b\neq 0 \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases}
ab^2=5b\\
b\neq 0 \end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}
 b\cdot (ab-5)=0\\
b\neq 0\end{cases}\iff ab=5$$
I a general way: $$\dfrac{A}{B}=C\iff \begin{cases}
B\cdot \dfrac{A}{B}=B\cdot C\\
B\neq 0 \end{cases}$$